# redirect()->intended('/login') not working laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-socialite

I'm using a custom SocialLoginController to log my users with facebook or google in al Laravel 5.3 project

In some cases I send to users an email with info about one change and the URL to the resource, for example `https://myweb.com/settings/profile/[the-uuid]`

when the user tries to access but is not logged in, he's redirected to the Handler@render() where I send it to login with `return redirect()->guest('/login');` and after login with social account I redirect them using `return redirect()->intended('/home')` but since I don't use the LoginController, the redirection to the requested URL is not working.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: return redirect('/home') ; would that not work for you?

Comment: No, since I want to redirect to the first requested resource, not to the homepage. Using the original LoginController the redirect()->intended() works fine, but I use a custom social login controller

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the request object is lost after redirect the user to login with facebook or google, so I fixed by saving the requested URI in a session variable and then checking if exists after redirect

`return Session::get('intended') ? redirect()->to(\Session::get('intended')) : redirect()->to('/expenses');`

Maybe this could help someone

Comment: the request object is not lost after redirect, it still knows the page to redirect to